# delete.on.null.values in MongoDB Kafka Connector not working

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I'm working on MongoDB Kafka Connector and i'm able to successfully Create and Update records but not able to delete records in connector config I'm using this config

```
{
"name": "mongo-sink",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "test",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb://mongo1:27018,mongo2:27019,mongo3:27020",
    "database": "accounting",
    "collection": "test",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "document.id.strategy": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialKeyStrategy",
    "document.id.strategy.partial.key.projection.list":"productId",
    "document.id.strategy.partial.key.projection.type":"ALLOWLIST",
    "writemodel.strategy":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy",
    "delete.on.null.values": "true",
    "transforms":"WrapKey",
    "transforms.WrapKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField$Key",
    "transforms.WrapKey.field":"_id"
}
```

}

not able to delete records if I'm sending the null records the document is updated with null not deleting any idea?

Comment: How are you sending your null records? Can you add an example of your message to the question?

Comment: @AmitSingh this is my message
{
  key: "898900",
    value: {
      productId: 1,
      productName: null
    },
    headers: {
      type: "test-value",
      subject: "test-value",
      correlationId: 'test',
    }
}

Comment: This is the message you are sending for deletion?

Comment: Yes I also put both productid and Name null but no luck it'll update both records with null

Comment: For deletion your value should be set to null so your key: "898900" and value: null

Comment: It make sense but i want to delete records based on matched projection.list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [MongoDB Sink](https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/current/kafka-sink-properties) docs,

> delete.on.null.values
>
> boolean
>
> Whether the connector should delete documents with matching key values when ***value is null***.

You have to set your message in the format :

```js
{"key" : "xyz", "value" : null, ... }
```

Comment: can i delete record that matched with projection.list ?

Comment: Projection.list is for whitelisting or blacklisting fields right?

Comment: Then how do you propose to use that for matching? Can you provide the details for the same in the question?